# PL/SQL - Calling attributes from another table - Undefined action

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute the following query. Which I believe should work however I seem to not run the `CREATE Statement`

The cause of this is this piece of logic `Loco_No.Loco_Class_No.Max_Tow_Weight` which I am not sure works in PL/SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Train
  (Train_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
   Loco_No integer
     REFERENCES Locomotive(Loco_No),
   Back_Loco_No float
     REFERENCES Locomotive(Loco_No),
   Train_Length float
     CONSTRAINT Train_Len
       CHECK(Train_Length <= 400),
   Train_Weight float
     CONSTRAINT Train_Weight
       CHECK(Train_Weight <= Loco_No.Loco_Class_No.Max_Tow_Weight)));
```

Am i unable to call my `Max_Tow_Weight` like this?

My other tables for reference

```
CREATE TABLE Locomotive
 (Loco_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Serial_No integer UNIQUE,
  Loco_Class_No integer
    REFERENCES Locomotive_Class(Loco_Class_No),
  Loco_name varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE Locomotive_Class
 (Loco_Class_No integer PRIMARY KEY,
  Max_Tow_Weight float NOT NULL,
  Loco_Class_Len float NOT NULL);
```

**Update**

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOCOWEIGHT 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Locomotive_Class
REFERENCING NEW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      SELECT Train_Weight FROM locomotive
   IF (Train_Weight < MAX_TOW_WEIGHT) THEN
       RAISE cError;    
EXCEPTION
WHEN cError THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_EXCEPTION('Train weight has exceeded max tow weight');
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHECK constraints can only refer to columns in the table on which they are defined.  Inline CHECK constraints are further limited to only referring to the column on which the constraint is defined, while out-of-line CHECK constraints can refer to multiple columns in the table being defined.  All CHECK constraints are prohibited from containing any of the following:

- Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
- Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE, SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)
- Calls to user-defined functions
- Dereferencing of REF columns (for example, using the DEREF function)
- Nested table columns or attributes
- The pseudocolumns CURRVAL, NEXTVAL, LEVEL, or ROWNUM
- Date constants that are not fully specified

[Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAEDFIB).

It looks to me that your construct of LOCO.LOCO_CLASS.MAX_TOW_WEIGHT is meant to refer to a table (LOCO), then another table (LOCO_CLASS), and then a column of the second table (MAX_TOW_WEIGHT).  This syntax is not correct, and there's really not a way that I can see to directly get at the data you're trying to reference.  In this case I think that a trigger (probably BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE) might be useful to determine if this condition is satisfied.  In this trigger you'd want to perform a SELECT to get the MAX_TOW_WEIGHT for the LOCO_CLASS, then compare that weight to the TRAIN_WEIGHT.  If the comparison fails (that is, TRAIN_WEIGHT > MAX_TOW_WEIGHT) the code would need to throw a user-defined exception, which the code which executed the INSERT or UPDATE would need to be written to handle.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Could I potentially have the following. Please see the update thank you for responding

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track (no pun intended :-).  If it were me I'd put the ON INSERT OR UPDATE trigger on TRAIN and within the trigger I'd `SELECT lc.MAX_WEIGHT FROM LOCOMOTIVE l INNER JOIN LOCO_CLASS lc ON (lc.LOCO_CLASS_NO = l.LOCO_CLASS_NO) WHERE l.LOCO_NO = :NEW.LOCO_NO` to compare to TRAIN.TRAIN_WEIGHT.

Comment: Very in-depth answer very well deserved!